# Selenium unable to click checkboxes [error: element could not be scrolled into view]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a piece of code that is able to click on all checkboxes that match my description. the code is:

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.CLASS_NAME, 'label__bPOQ33bu')))

except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

checkboxes = []
checkboxes = driver.find_elements(by.CLASS_NAME, 'label__bPOQ33bu')

for checkbox in checkboxes:
    checkbox.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    checkbox.click()
```

when this code is run, I get the error:

[image]

This is what the html code I'm trying to hit, looks like (specifically I'm trying to hit the one that is marked.):

[image]

I've tried running it in different browsers aswell. in chrome, nothing happens at all, not even an error, but I get this error when I run it in firefox.

Comment: to those interested, I have tried with XPATH instead of classname, which did not do anything at all. my XPATH looked like "'//label[@class="label__bPOQ33bu"]'"

Comment: Share the HTML in the form of text not image.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to perform the checkbox `click()` on its `<input>` node, and not `<label>` node. So, change your XPath to locate `input` node.

Even after that if it gives `ElementNotInteractableException`, then try using Java script to perform click() as below:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

**UPDATE:** Try the below code:

```
checkboxes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class='input__60nH7vJR')]")
```

Use the below code within your `for` loop to click on `checkbox`

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkbox)
```

Comment: I've done that now, where my xpath is "driver.find_elements(by.XPATH, "//input[@class='input__60nH7vJR']")". now the error has dissaperead, but still nothing is checked

Comment: Try the code in the updated answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I get the error "selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: arguments[0].click is not a function", which is weird, because I did not get that error on the code before the update

Comment: when I do that, the exception I'm getting becomes: "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[contains(@class='input__60nH7vJR')]' is not a valid XPath expression."

Comment: `//input[contains(@class,'input__60nH7vJR')]` -- After `@class` replace `=` with `,`

Comment: hmm, now I do not get any error messages, but the checkboxes are not clicked. does it perhaps have something to do with the checkbox being hidden, until the mouse hovers above it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252447/discussion-between-shawn-and-andreas-ravnholt).